# Ошибка в коде, не могу найти ошибу

Tags: c#

Не могу найти ошибку в коде.Перепроверил код кучу раз исправил несколько ошибок ,но не на мог найти остальные помогите

пишет ошибка cs1002

Вот мой код:

```cs
public class playermove : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector2 moveVector;
    
    void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        walk();
    }
   
    void walk()
    {
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = nev Vector2 (moveVector.x, rb.velocity.y);
    } }
```

Comment: ошибка явно не в этом скрипте

Comment: Вот почему я не могу найти ошибку . тогда с чем может быть связана ошибка?

Comment: Есть полный текст ошибки, в котором всё написано..... На крайняк написать скрипт руками заново

Answer (score 3):

заменить

```
nev
```

на

```
new
```

---

И впредь использовать IDE для написания кода, который показывает все всплывающие ключевые слова в языке